# Scrollable dropdown div that ends at bottom of screen

Tags: css

In the following example, the div has the pre-defined height of: `300px`. 
The last city of the scrollable dropdown is `Zimbawe` and does not get displayed on an iPhone 6 screen for example.

I want to change the scrollable dropdown div in such a way to not specify the height and make the div end where the screen ends.

Any ideas ?

The library we use fro the dropdown is: 
https://github.com/mukeshsoni/react-telephone-input

An you can see here the default height of the dropdown non dynamic:
https://github.com/mukeshsoni/react-telephone-input/blob/master/src/ReactTelephoneInput.js#L477

[image]

Comment: If the problem is only on iPhone then I think it should be fine, since from what I know they use their own display for the drop-down menu

Comment: No it's not only on iPhone. I just gave an example. It's on any small screens where the div overflows the screen.

Comment: Please give your sample code

Comment: The library we use for the dropdown is https://github.com/mukeshsoni/react-telephone-input .

Answer (score 1):

try this out, setting height depending upon the viewport(vh).

```
.div {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

`{height: 100vh;}` matches the height of the viewport.

Comment: This would make the div as big as the viewport height .. I want the div to start from the dropdown button where it starts right now and end where the screen ends.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**CSS**

```
div { // change selector
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: By doing so the height of the div will be huge, as big as the list of flag goes.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile, such dropdown should appear as full overlay. Exactly like the `select` element options would appear on mobile.

Target mobile devices using `@media` and use `position: fixed;` with the respective positions and size (explore `vh` and `vw` units). Than use `overflow-y: auto;` to make your modal list scrollable.

Answer (score -1):

try adding max height and overflow

```
 .div {
        max-height: 150px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

you have to adjust the max-height according to screen size manually.